# How to use else single line statement in Perl ?

Tags: perl, if-statement

I am beginner to Perl , I have trying to read the if...else statement.
I tried if..else statement with curly braces.

```
if ( 1 ) { 
   print "True\n";  } 
else { 
 print "False\n" ; }
```

It working properly , then I searched in net how to use single line if statement without using curly braces, they provided same code.

```
     print "True\n" if (1 ) ;
```

I tried to use the else statement with that sample code

```
  print "false\n" else ;
```

But I got error message .Can anybody explain how to use the single line else statement with if statement in perl.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`Ternary or conditional operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator):

```
print 1 ? "True\n" : "false\n";
```

**Update**

Here's another way to get it all on one line:

```
if ( 1 ) { print "True\n";  } else { print "False\n" ; }
```

Comment: without using Ternary or conditional operator any other way ?

Comment: Sure, I've edited my post to provide another way to get an `if` statement all on one line.

Comment: @Miller, If there is any way to use else statement like this if statement, print "True\n" if (1 ) ;

Comment: @Chandru No.  The only way would be to duplicate the test in the negative.  `print "true" if $test;`  And then `print "false" if !$test;`

Comment: Testing `$test` and subsequently testing `!$test` is not quite the same as an `if`/`else`. The duplicated boolification of the `$test` variable allows tied variable or overloaded object shenanigans. For example, here's a variable which seems to be both true and false... `perl -MTie::Cycle -E'tie my $test, "Tie::Cycle" => [1, 0]; say "true" if $test; say "false" if !$test;'`

Comment: @ikegami: I'm not sure how that is relevant to my comment. My point is that you would normally expect exactly one of `$test` and `!$test` to be true, and the other to be false. However due to ties and overloading they could *both evaluate to true* (or both to false). Thus checking `if $test` followed by testing `if !$test` is not the same as an `if($test){...}else{...}` statement. With `if`/`else` *exactly one* code block is guaranteed to be executed. There is no situation where they'll both get executed.

Comment: @tobyink I was in no way advocating he duplicate the condition.  Yes, it is theoretically possible that the variable could be a tied.  However, the bigger issue is that one should not needlessly duplicate code like that as it introduces risk of a simple mistype.  I find the OP's question to be overly contrived by this persistence to "find another way".  Hence my joke answer in the update.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is `unless`:

1. if condition is true, do something

   print "True" if 1;
2. if condition is false, do something

   print "False" unless 1;

Answer (score 3):

The postfix form of if, like this:

```
print "blah" if $x==1;
```

Is referred to as a "statement modifier". The list of all supported statement modifiers can be found in [perlsyn](http://p3rl.org/perlsyn). It is:

- `if EXPR`
- `unless EXPR`
- `while EXPR`
- `until EXPR`
- `for LIST`
- `foreach LIST`
- `when EXPR`

Note that `else` and `elsif` are not amongst them. That means that if you need elsif or else clauses attached to your if, you need to use the longhand form.